# Solder for steamed pudding mold

Tags: food-safety, equipment

My small steamed pudding mold has sprung a leak.  What type of solder should be use to repair the leak?  Thanks,

Comment: Hi Bill, and welcome. As none of us have ever been to your kitchen, it would lay helpful to know exactly what kind of material your mold is made of. I assume something metal (because you said solder) but it could be anything...

Answer (score 4):

**If** it's copper or brass you should be able to use solder used for drinking water plumbing (tin with a little copper, and no flux in it). This will probably work on tin or tin plate as well.

You'll probably need to use separate flux as well. Again get something used for potable water. Give it a very good wash and rinse afterwards.

For more advice you can probably look at what people do for brewing. This has actually been [discussed on diy stack exchange before](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8334/what-flux-should-i-use-for-copper-that-will-be-used-for-food-prep).